# Clearing APC cache with postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, apc

I was looking for a suitable caching solution for a PHP app.

I decided to let the application do all the "first of all I must land on the right server within the cluster", so I use the much faster APC cache, rather then memcache.

It does include an overhead, to find(in terms of improving the caching) the right server to land on, but I kind of like it.

I heard there was a project pgmemcache, to for example clear outdated memcached entries from within postgres triggers.

I do handle outdated date my own way, but Im still curious if theres something out there to acces APC cache from within postgres triggers.

Thanks in advance,
kriscom

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any equivalent of pgmemcache for APC.  Pgmemcache is open source, so you could use it as a basis for creating an APC equivalent: https://github.com/Ormod/pgmemcache.

If it is OK for your cache to be a little stale, you could create a table in Postgres to function as an invalidation/update queue.  Use a trigger to insert a row when the cache needs to be updated.  Then create a PHP script that constantly polls the queue and performs the cache manipulations.

I would not suggest spreading your cache management across layers.  Either do it all in you data access layer or all at the database layer but don't mix them.

Comment: I do agree, that a clear separation is more often very helpfull... in many ways... but I think in that particular case I would sacrifice it to trigger the database only when it is needed... but if there would be no other way, I think I may do it... thanks...

Comment: Hey... I just kind of felt I did not wanted to do it and now I even exactly know why... those objects Im polling from database and caching ond the php servers are realy simple operations... for today there is not a single join needed to fetch them... it could change in time... when they grow, maybe I would use that suggestion... I think I was considering it while I was thinking about it after all...